# Calling @Test method in a Test method or Calling a class in a Test method?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

As i posted earlier, we can't put a test code in After method or Before method.

My scenario is like i have 10 test methods after each method i have to run another test method.

Please let me know the answer for this if one knows...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Test methods but specify the priority to execute.

```
 @Test( priority = 1 )
 public void test1() {
 System.out.println("test1");
 }

@Test( priority = 2 )
public void test2() {
System.out.println("test2");
```

}

```
@Test( priority = 3 )
public void test3() {
System.out.println("test3");
}
```

in this way you can executed test methods on specified order. I hope it will helps you.

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow a basic java code, call methods from One class in to Another

```
Class A

public class A {

static void method1()
{
    System.out.println("Selenium_1");
}
static void method2()
{
    System.out.println("Selenium_1");
}

}


Class B

public class B extends A {

public static void main(String ar[])
{
    method1();
    method2();
}
}
```

Hope this solution may help your problem.